# name 'guild' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I am coding a bot to find users with the 'Admin' role on my discord server and do  print information *(**admin** username)* and store all roles in a list `peopleWithRole`:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
role_name = "Admin"
peopleWithRole = []

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    role = discord.utils.find(
        lambda r: r.name == role_name, guild.roles)
        
    for user in guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            peopleWithRole.append(user)

bot.run("My token")
```

However, when  I run this, returns **error** `'guild'` is not defined. I  am just starting out with **discord** `python` module. How should I use client or `bot` in this situation?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
role_name = "Admin"
peopleWithRole = []

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print("------")
    guild = bot.guilds[0]

    role = discord.utils.find(
        lambda r: r.name == role_name, guild.roles)
        
    for user in guild.members:
        if role in user.roles:
            peopleWithRole.append(user)

bot.run("My token")
```

In your find call you reference guild.roles but have never defined guild. You need to select the guild (I believe guilds is a member of bot)

This is a fairly basic python error to debug, and any IDE would identify what is wrong. I suggest you look up some tutorials on how to debug.

Comment: Is there something I can use instead of guild? I just saw other people using it and I just thought guild was just the way of saying server. I thought guild.members was talking about all of the members of the server

Comment: it is... if guild = a discord.Guild object instance.  Right now it's an undefined variable.

Comment: i'm standing up a test instance to fix your code... but again, you just need to select the proper guild from your bot object.

Comment: Can you explain further? I made a variable guild = discord.Guild, but that gives me another error 'property' object is not iterable

Comment: Ok, that test instance would be helpful

Comment: ok I copied your code into an IDE.  It IMMEDIATELY underline guild as an undefined variable.

Comment: I'm having some certificate error, so can't verify this code right now.  But the added line should work.

Comment: ok, it worked for me, as long as your have a role called "Admin" on your server...

Comment: I'm not being unfriendly.  Your questions show you do not understand how python works, like the very basics.  There is nothing wrong with that.  However you are attempting to use a library that requires advanced understanding of python (the library developers repeatedly say this if you ever visit their discord channel).  You do not have basic understanding, so you should start somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will practise my raw python skills for a week now and then move on to discord.py

Comment: That is a good idea. I wish you the best of luck. I strongly recommend you learn to use an IDE with a debugger. I recommend pycharm, but there are many options (pycharm has a learning curve, but the debugger is very powerful). Once you get some practice go back to this problem and see if you can solve it and understand how your errors occurred.

Comment: Also please not my solution was a naive one. This only works if you are only connected to one guild with your bot... otherwise it will just pick the first guild to run on. I figured you were probably only connected to one guild right now. Just a hunch.

Comment: Yep, just coding a bot for my server with a bunch of friends.